# Create response to disco info Android

Tags: android

I'm developping an Android application in which I need to implement XMPP, so I'm using asmack.

I need to response to `disco#info` request from server. I want to create a response like that :

```
<iq id="123" type="result" to="x" from="y">
  <xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
  <identity category="client" type="bot" name="oo" uid="{1111-2222-3333}"/>
  <feature var="urn:xmpp:ping"/>
  <feature var="jabber:iq:version">
  <feature var="bb" version="123"/>
</iq>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to add `uid` and the version in the feature.
I have already do something :

```
ServiceDiscoveryManager discoManager =ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);`
discoManager.setIdentityName("oo");
discoManager.setIdentityType("bot");
discoManager.addFeature("urn:xmpp:ping");
discoManager.addFeature("bb");
```

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it's not possible to add something else in identity or feature.
To add information to your disco info response you can add extended info to you discomanager :

```
//Add uid
DataForm Data = new DataForm("result");
FormField fielduid = new FormField("name");
fielduid.setLabel("System UID");
fielduid.addValue(randomUUID);
Data.addField(fielduid);
discoManager.setExtendedInfo(Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't jnow anything on Android development, but it looks like you're missing `/` on the third feature declaration to close the line

Your line :

```
<feature var="jabber:iq:version">
```

What I suggest :

```
<feature var="jabber:iq:version"/>
```

Comment: Yes, i did that, but the problem is to add the uid and the version.. Thank you for responding